# Domino ACL - redirect to page with multiple authentication choices

Tags: authentication, authorization, xpages, acl, saml-2.0

I'm trying to create a Domino Xpages 9.0 application which has multiple authentication methods, these being SAML 2.0 via an IDP, and standard lotus notes authentication with the domcfg login form.

My problem comes from the fact that when my ACL redirects an unauthorised user from accessing a page, they are presented with only with the idp website (the authorisation method which is currently listed in the server document).

Is it possible to instead redirect to a login xpage, from which i can then present the user with a choice of login methods? If this is not possible, is there another (better) way of achieving this functionality?

Thanks very much,

Paul

Comment: I am not sure that this is possible to achieve. We had a similar need, but in our case we couldn't even get Domino to act as a Service Provider with our IdP. So we ended up with an Apache reverse proxy and a Shibboleth SP in front of the Domino. Anyway, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could make the application accessiable for Anonymous Access and then in the beforepageload event if the user=Anonymous you can redirect them to your own Pre Login Xpage.

Not the best idea but it works.

Comment: thanks. unfortunately this would not be an option due to data sensitivity. Providing anonymous access to just the login page would also not work, as locked pages accessed directly (ie through bookmarks) would only redirect to saml.

Comment: This solution is secure. Your data is already protected by readers fields and or even better moved on an interanl server not exposed in the web. All XPages are using their own acl setting so anonymous cant do anything and you have an additional layer of access in your application that you can control.